Can I make a pipe save data to disk instead of blocking until the reader can continue?
Are there any established tools where the pipe spills to disk rather than blocking the upstream process?
As an example, in a traditional pipeline A | B, we get the following behavior when B does not read from stdin:

A emits output until stdout fills up
Then A is blocked until B reads from stdin

I'd like the following behavior instead:

A emits output until its stdout buffer fills up
Further output from A is written to an on-disk cache file, so A is not blocked
When B ingests data from stdin, new data from the on-disk cache file is read (FIFO) into the buffer

Is there any existing tool that accomplishes this?
Thank you!

Very nearly a duplicate of a very old question. The difference is that you ask for buffering to disk, while the other question says "in memory".

Thanks @Kusalananda, that's a useful link.

Uh, such a "pipe" is called a "regular file", isn't it? Does A > somefile & tail -f somefile | B fit your requirements? (You'll probably also want the --pid option to tail to make it exit once A exits, or a similar way of terminating the whole thing.) If not, why?

@TooTea Depending on how fast A writes to the file, that pipeline might omit to give B the start of the data.  tail -f file will follow the data written to the file, but will start by showing only the last 10 lines of the given file.

@Kusalananda Of course, I just forgot the crucial -c +0 while typing that.

@Kusalananda Buffering to memory is effectively the same as buffering to disk, since virtual memory is paged to swap space when necessary.

@Barmar I would agree, but I don't know how ulimit resource limits plays into that. Also, mbuffer allows you to specify exactly where you want to store the file that you buffer into, and it avoids using swap which may be used by other parts of the system already (and it may be smaller than what you want for your buffering). {Shrug}

@Kusalananda True, ulimit would limit it.

With the mbuffer utility:
producer | mbuffer -t -m 10G | consumer

This would cause mbuffer to use a memory-mapped file (the -t option) to buffer the potentially massive amount of data that producer outputs if consumer can't read it fast enough. The size of the memory-mapped file would be limited to 10 GB (if that file fills up, mbuffer would block as usual).
